# Eclipse GWT Java Tomcat - Serialisation policy issue when I upload to the hosting server

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, gwt

I have made a change to my application using Eclipse (4.3.2) and GWT and tested it on my local Tomcat where it works. However when I upload it to the hosting server (I do a full upload not just the classes I changed) I get the following error in the logs when I try to use it (login):

```
INFO: Server startup in 20107 ms
Nov 04, 2014 5:41:33 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: mySQLConnection: ERROR: The serialization policy file '/org.AwardTracker.AwardTracker/C7227FD579DD02DA4BB5B3EBAD09AE79.gwt.rpc' was not found; did you forget to include it in this deployment?
Nov 04, 2014 5:41:33 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: mySQLConnection: WARNING: Failed to get the SerializationPolicy 'C7227FD579DD02DA4BB5B3EBAD09AE79' for module 'http://tc1165.metawerx.com.au/org.AwardTracker.AwardTracker/'; a legacy, 1.3.3 compatible, serialization policy will be used.  You may experience SerializationExceptions as a result.
Nov 04, 2014 5:41:40 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
SEVERE: Exception while dispatching incoming RPC call
com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.SerializationException: Type 'org.AwardTracker.client.ViewData' was not assignable to 'com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.IsSerializable' and did not have a custom field serializer.For security purposes, this type will not be serialized.: instance = org.AwardTracker.client.ViewData@62066d5c



    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamWriter.serialize(ServerSerializationStreamWriter.java:667)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.AbstractSerializationStreamWriter.writeObject(AbstractSerializationStreamWriter.java:130)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamWriter$ValueWriter$8.write(ServerSerializationStreamWriter.java:153)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamWriter.serializeValue(ServerSerializationStreamWriter.java:587)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.encodeResponse(RPC.java:605)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.encodeResponseForSuccess(RPC.java:471)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:563)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processCall(RemoteServiceServlet.java:265)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processPost(RemoteServiceServlet.java:305)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.doPost(AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.java:62)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:277)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:274)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAsPrivileged(Subject.java:536)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.execute(SecurityUtil.java:309)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.doAsPrivilege(SecurityUtil.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:297)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.access$000(ApplicationFilterChain.java:55)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain$1.run(ApplicationFilterChain.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain$1.run(ApplicationFilterChain.java:187)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:186)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:277)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:274)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAsPrivileged(Subject.java:536)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.execute(SecurityUtil.java:309)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.doAsPrivilege(SecurityUtil.java:249)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:237)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.access$000(ApplicationFilterChain.java:55)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain$1.run(ApplicationFilterChain.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain$1.run(ApplicationFilterChain.java:187)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:186)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.

java:745)

0    [catalina-exec-12] INFO  gwtupload.server.UploadServlet  - UPLOAD-SERVLET init: maxSize=3145728, slowUploads=0, isAppEngine=false, corsRegex=^$
2    [catalina-exec-12] INFO  gwtupload.server.UploadServlet  - UPLOAD-ACTION init: removeSessionFiles=false, removeData=false
```

The change I made was to:
 AccountUpdateView.java where I added a Label and a TextBox to display the "Group" (client side)
 AccountAndCubs.java where I added the new field (get and set) to be displayed in AccountUpdateView.java (client side)
 MySQLConnection.java where I added the new field to the sql call (server side)

In my searches I found some information relating to this that suggested that I add "static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;" to the class I changed (AccountUpdateView.java) which I did however I still get this error.

I noticed this line:

```
SEVERE: Exception while dispatching incoming RPC call
com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.SerializationException: Type 'org.AwardTracker.client.ViewData' was not assignable to 'com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.IsSerializable' and did not have a custom field serializer.For security purposes, this type will not be serialized.: instance = org.AwardTracker.client.ViewData@62066d5c
```

Which indicates an issue with "ViewData.java" which I have not changed and does already have:

```
package org.AwardTracker.client;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class ViewData implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
```

Your help with this would be greatly appreciated. Also, I am not very technical and am still learning so please be patient with me and use simple language.

---

Added as requested:

ViewData code:

```
package org.AwardTracker.client;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class ViewData implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String accountId;
    private String accountLevel;
    private String ymId;
    private String awId;
    private String adAwardGroup;
    private String adScoutGroup;

    public ViewData() {
        //just here because GWT wants it.
    }

    public String getaccountId() {
        return accountId;
    }   
    public void setaccountId(String accountId) {
        this.accountId = accountId;
    }

    public String getaccountLevel() {
        return accountLevel;
    }   
    public void setaccountLevel(String accountLevel) {
        this.accountLevel = accountLevel;
    }

    public String getymId() {
        return ymId;
    }   
    public void setymId(String ymId) {
        this.ymId = ymId;
    }

    public String getawId() {
        return awId;
    }   
    public void setawId(String awId) {
        this.awId = awId;
    }

    public String getadAwardGroup() {
        return adAwardGroup;
    }
    public void setadAwardGroup(String adAwardGroup) {
        this.adAwardGroup = adAwardGroup;
    }

    public String getadScoutGroup() {
        return adScoutGroup;
    }
    public void setadScoutGroup(String adScoutGroup) {
        this.adScoutGroup = adScoutGroup;
    }

}
```

AccountsAndCubs.java code ("group" has been added):

```
package org.AwardTracker.client;

import com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.IsSerializable;
import java.util.Date;

public class AccountAndCubs implements IsSerializable {

    static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    //@SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private String accountId;
    //@SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private String emailaddress;
    //@SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private String password;
    //@SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private String level;
    //@SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private String pack;
    //@SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private Integer enabled;
    //@SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private Date archived;
    //@SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private String group;
    //@SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private String acaId;
    //@SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private String cdId;
    //@SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private String surname;
    //@SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private String firstname;

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private AccountAndCubs() {
        //just here because GWT wants it.
    }
    public AccountAndCubs(String accountId, String emailaddress, String password, String level, String pack,
            Integer enabled, Date archived, String group, String acaId, String cdId, String surname, String firstname) {
        this.accountId = accountId;
        this.emailaddress = emailaddress;
        this.password = password;
        this.level = level;
        this.pack = pack;
        this.enabled = enabled;
        this.archived = archived;
        this.group = group;
        this.acaId = acaId;
        this.cdId = cdId;
        this.surname = surname;
        this.firstname = firstname;
    }

    public String getAccountId() {
        return accountId;
    }
    public void setAccountId(String accountId) {
        this.accountId = accountId;
    }

    public String getEmailAddress() {
        return emailaddress;
    }
    public void setEmailAddress(String emailaddress) {
        this.emailaddress = emailaddress;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getLevel() {
        return level;
    }
    public void setLevel(String level) {
        this.level = level;
    }

    public String getPack() {
        return pack;
    }
    public void setPack(String pack) {
        this.pack = pack;
    }

    public Integer getEnabled() {
        return enabled;
    }
    public void setEnabled(Integer enabled) {
        this.enabled = enabled;
    }

    public Date getArchived() {
        return archived;
    }
    public void setArchived(Date archived) {
        this.archived = archived;
    }

    public String getGroup() {
        return group;
    }
    public void setGroup(String group) {
        this.group = group;
    }

    public String getAcaId() {
        return acaId;
    }
    public void setAcaId(String acaId) {
        this.acaId = acaId;
    }

    public String getCdId() {
        return cdId;
    }
    public void setCdId(String cdId) {
        this.cdId = cdId;
    }

    public String getSurname() {
        return surname;
    }
    public void setSurname(String surname) {
        this.surname = surname;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstname;
    }
    public void setFirstName(String firstname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
    }

}
```

Comment: This looks correct, you might need to clean, build and redeploy.

Comment: Hi @ChrisHinshaw, In Eclipse I already did a Refresh, Clean and then GWT Compile. Would there be a reason why it works on my Tomcat and not the host Tomcat or is that not unusual?

Comment: Are you sure ViewData is still serializable as per the [requirements](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideServerCommunication.html#DevGuideSerializableTypes)? It didn't change, but maybe one of its fields did and is no longer serializable? And what do you mean you did "full upload"? Did you also update the RPC serialization manifests (*.gwt.rpc files)? And all the permutations that GWT compiler produces?

Comment: Hi @IgorKlimer, Sorry I do not understand. If I did not change ViewData.java how could one of it's fields have changed? I did a full upload by copying the war, removed /WEB-INF/lib/gwt-dev.jar, zipped the contents, renamed the zipped file to ROOT.war and then uploaded. Once it had uploaded I restarted the Tomcat service. I will try uploading just the classes that changed however, if this works, this will not help me in the future if I need to do a full upload. Kind regards, Glyn

Comment: You mentioned that you changed `AccountCubAssociation` - if it's a field in `ViewData` and because of the change `AccountCubAssociation` is no longer serializable then `ViewData` also won't be serializable. Please post the whole code - `ViewData`, `AccountCubAssociation`. But I'd bet your manual deployment is the source of the problem - have you tried a build tool like Ant, Maven or Gradle? In the long run, it's worth the effort.

Comment: Hi @IgorKlimer, Thank you very much for your help. I will post the code above. I have not tried a build tool as I am just using the instructions from the Hoster. Are build tools easy to use and which do you recommend please? I will look up the ones you mentioned. Regards, Glyn

Comment: Hi @IgorKlimer, I notice that I mentioned AccountCubAssociation this should be AccountAndCubs. sorry if this causes any confusion. I have corrected my post. Regards, Glyn

Comment: Thanks for the source code. "Unfortunately", it looks OK, the models should be serializable without problems. So Chris' original suggestion stands: clean, build and redeploy. It seems your current deployment method is not updating the whole application properly. Either recheck with the [documentation](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideDeploying.html) that you are doing everything manually or look into [Maven](http://mojo.codehaus.org/gwt-maven-plugin/) (I'd say it's easiest for you since it's mature and there are tons of tutorials and samples).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@IgorKlimer, @ChrisHinshaw Thank you for your help.

After a fair bit of trial and error I have finally got this to work. Just in case you would like to know (it would help you out in the future) I:

1. Deleted the ROOT.war (to upload I need to zip the war and rename the zipped file to ROOT.war, this is automatically picked up and installed when I upload it to the host's server) from the host's server and did a restart
2. Once restarted I uploaded my working (on my server) ROOT.war
3. Restarted the server
4. Once restarted I tried the application - same problem
5. For some reason I went up a level on the host's server to private-cgi-bin and found another ROOT.war so I deleted it
6. I then went back to private-cgi-bin/tomcat and deleted the ROOT.war
7. I then restarted the server
8. Once restarted I then uploaded my ROOT.war
9. Once uploaded I restarted the server
10. Once restarted I went into Tomcat Manager and selected Reload
11. I then started Chrome and cleared the cache
12. I then tried the application and it worked, I checkd my changes and they are there and work, I did some more testes and checked the system log - all OK.

Regards,

Glyn

Answer (score 0):

Though, I haven't figured out the actual fix (can't try yours , because can't delete ROOT.war in testing environments) , I got some workaround which might be useful for others.

Main issue in the above question is :

> The serialization policy file '/org.AwardTracker.AwardTracker/C7227FD579DD02DA4BB5B3EBAD09AE79.gwt.rpc' was not found; did you forget to include it in this deployment?

Normally this is happening because deployed WAR file contains app folder and inside of it there is a rpc file. However due to some issues with tomcat cache or any other , it still looking for old rpc file that is used in previous deployment.

So work around is, take a backup of previous file and copy to app folder again.

[image: app folder Structure]